# Block layout - List of all blocks

Tags: blocks, 8

I'm having a question about the Block layout in Drupal 8. A couple of months ago (I don't know which beta it was) the block layout looked like this:

[image]

As you can see there's a list of blocks at the right of the page. Now in the current beta of Drupal 8 (beta 14) it looks like this:

[image]

The list of all blocks is gone. Why did they deleted this? And is there an easy way to get this back?

Comment: I believe that the only place *"Why did they deleted this?"* can really be answered is issue queue, because there developers who made changes will see it. As for getting it back, have you looked at source? Maybe it's still there, just failed to display? No errors in JS console? What do you see when you click "Place block" next to region name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same list shows up when you click on Place block. Doesn't look quite the same, but it is.

It was moved because they did UX testing and not a single person managed to place a block in D8, they all completely ignored the right sidebar. So a different solution had to be found, which is currently definitely not very nice yet.

This is the issue: [#2513580: Implement the new block layout design to emphasize the primary interaction of placing a block](https://www.drupal.org/node/2512456)

Comment: I like this new design better too.